# What is the"$ref" in msgraph and is it related to ReferenceRequestBuilder in the sdk

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Reading through the [Microsoft Graph REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0) documentation, and I see URL paths ending in "$ref", for example [The Add Member Example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0#example).  What is "$ref"?

Also what is the ReferencesRequest prefix in the [.net sdk](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)?

Answer (score 1):

$ref indicates relationship between entities and a POST on $ref is for creating a new relationship between entities.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4#creating-a-relationship-between-entities

Answer (score 0):

[This document](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/concepts/query-parameters.md) mentions that most query parameters are compatible with the OData V4 Query Language, and $ref is defined for OData V4 [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752345).

Based off of this alone (I am unable to find a specification for MS Graph), I assume here that `$ref` is also used to get a reference to an item based on a relationship. Given the context of the example you've used, the `$ref` is being used to get a reference to the list of members for a particular group that you wish the new member added.